# Can not upload data in SAS studio

Tags: sas

Here is my code to upload the data.

```
Data HBAT;
Infile '/home/my_user_name/my_content/HBAT_652.xlsx' DLM = '09'X TRUNCOVER;
Input ID X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19
X20 X21 X22 X23;
*;
```

This my error that I get.

ERROR: The path /home/tmaciver7840/my_content/HBAT_652.xlsx is not in the list of accessible paths when SAS is in the lockdownstate.

Does anyone know where I went wrong? Thanks

Comment: Are you using SAS Studio with a server?  Or is this a virtual machine running SAS University Edition?  Or something else?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'm running SAS University edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error suggests you haven't set up your shared folders properly.  See [SAS Problem Note 53333](http://support.sas.com/kb/53/333.html) which suggests you read how to share folders properly:

> Here is another error that you might receive when attempting to access your 
>   data:
>
> `ERROR: The path /users/xxyyzz/Downloads/Cheatsheet.xlsx is invalid because it is not in the list of accessible paths when SAS is in the lockdown state.`
>
> If you see an error similar to this one, you might be referencing an improper folder in which to store your files. Review the instructions below to ensure that your shared folder is set up correctly.
>
> Alternatively, if your folder is set up properly, the problem might be that you are not accessing the folder properly. To make sure that you are accessing the folder correctly, see the LIBNAME/FILENAME documentation SAS University Edition: [Help Center](http://support.sas.com/software/products/university-edition/faq/SAS_libname.htm) page referenced above.

If you're using a server (and not the SAS University edition), your administrator may need to add the folder your data file is stored in to the list of approved locations.  See this [explanation of LOCKDOWN](http://www.sascommunity.org/planet/blog/category/lockdown/) on sascommunity.org for example.